# removing middle elements on paragraph using java

Tags: java, string, mongodb, scrapy, web-crawler

hi guys i wanna print the result from mongoDB on my project with tidy, i do some research on scrapy (for web crawler), and i show the result using java

but i have problem, the scrapy result when i print it on my project is become `"[ \"\\n\" , \"\\nThe \" , \" (Federal Bureau of Investigation) over a locked iPhone that belonged to one of the San Bernardino shooters may be over, but the Department of Justice (DoJ) are back in front of a judge with a similar request.\" , \"\\n\" , \"\\nThe American Civil Liberties Union (ACLU) has discovered publicly available \" , \" "`

my question is how to remove every `"\n" , "\n` or `" , "\n" , "\n` on paragraph using java, or anybody have idea to remove automatically empty elements on mongoDB using java? thanks before...

here the capture of my programs
[image: screenshoot programs and output]

Comment: Can you share you spider code, especially how you extract data from web pages? It's easier to amend at the spider level than try to clean the data afterwards in Java

Comment: its fixed mate :) i ask it on facebook

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the array of strings into a single string and then use a regex to replace all of the occurrences of "\n":

```
String paragraph = String.join(" ", mongoArray);
paragraph = paragraph.replaceAll("\\n" ,"");
```

If you want to keep it in the array form, you could do this in a similar way by iterating through the array:

```
ArrayList<String> paragraph = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < mongoArray.length; i++) {
    mongoArray[i] = mongoArray[i].replaceAll("\\n", "");
    if(mongoArray[i].length() > 0) {
        paragraph.push(mongoArray[i]);
    }
}
```

This way you only add the strings containing more than the newline into the paragraph ArrayList.

Comment: still error mate -_- i dunno the problem is on db or on java..
before the body elements (paragraph) i succes cutting for title,link, & date..but the body is so different because any empty elements on mongoDB

Comment: you still there @sam?